# "Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received" Django Channels

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I get this error only in chrome (not in safari and not in firefox) when trying to connect to the server via a websocket:
`Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received`.
The server accepts the connection but chrome unexpectedly closes it immediately.

This is how I create a websocket connection on the frontend:

```js
const websocket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/', ['Token', 'user_secret_token'])
```

This is how my `consumers.py` looks:

```py
class MyConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'example_room'

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

        self.accept()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the websocket protocol I was using (Token) as the subprotocol parameter when I call `self.accept()` on the server.

So here is how my consumer looks now:

```py
class MyConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_group_name = 'example_room'

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

        # incorrect
        # self.accept()

        # correct
        self.accept('Token')
```